# Distinct selection over multiple columns using JPQL?

Tags: jpa-2.0, distinct, jpql

I have a JPA entity ("Entity") which has three fields - "id", "field1" and "field2", all of which are of type long.

I'm trying to write a JPQL (named) query to retrieve all Entity objects but with distinct field1 "or" field2: I don't mean that the combination of these fields is distinct, but rather that each Entity in the resulted list will have a field1 value which no other Entity in the list has for either its field1 or field2, and same for field2. (I'd also like the query to be ordered by the "id" field, but that's probably besides the point).

I know how to do this using UNION in normal SQL, but I'd rather stick to JPQL queries. Since those don't support UNION, I've tried doing this in a number of various ways with DISTINCT, JOIN and what not, but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you provide the SQL you would use to solve this?